# Is there an API to get a user's favorite tags?

Tags: support, tag-watching, api

I'm looking into querying the API for a list of my favorite tags (for my account) once authenticated. It looks as if this is being persisted using a filter, but how can I retrieve this filter using the StackExchange API?

*Favorite* tag: it is favorited by the user on the web site. (This is irrelevant from user activity in that tag.)

I don't want to query another user's favorite tags, however if that's possible I'd be happy to learn as well.

Comment: Favorite tags or tags they're most active in?  I don't see favorite tags on other people's profile page, so I don't think that's made public through the API.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: This does not currently exist. It is not available on either the API or on the data.se site.